# How to prevent modifications of specific cells?

Tags: excel, vsto

Is it possible to prevent user-made modifications of some specific cells? I can use VSTO add-in for plugging into Excel events.

Comment: I know how to do it for vsto excel workbook. shall i post it as an answer ? code for the addin and workbook should be similar ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Worksheet.Change Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change%28VS.80%29.aspx). This event takes a Range object. As far as I remember this objects contains information about what cell(s) is selected. Then you can do with this cell whatever you want [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms281150.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My approach is slightly different.

I protect the complete sheet and then unlock particular cells or columns or rows, so user can fill details in those sheets. But you should get same results with this.

*Code has been tested on VS 2008.*

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            var activesheet = (Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveSheet;


            // keep particular cell unlocked 
            activesheet.get_Range("A1",missing).Locked = false;

            // keep entire row unlocked 

            activesheet.get_Range("B2", missing).EntireRow.Locked = false;

            // keep entire column unlocked 

            activesheet.get_Range("C1", missing).EntireColumn.Locked = false;

            // keep particular range (D4 - E8) unlocked 

            activesheet.get_Range("D4","E8").Locked = false;

            activesheet.Protect(missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);


        }
```

When user clicks on the locked cell, excel throws alert message saying cell is locked. Its annoying for user. You may disable `displayalerts`.

Just use

```
this.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

in the `ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` just before declaring `var activesheet` and do not forget the enable it in again using

```
private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.DisplayAlerts = true;
        }
```

This will take care of the annoying alert message.